# How can I write a unit test for the SPECS framework without splitting my code into separate functions?

Tags: rust, specs

I'm trying to write tests for my Rust program that is using the SPECS framework. I'm not sure how to run unit tests on the system's `run` function because it uses the framework's storage types to read values. Does anyone have a good method for getting around this? Here is my code for a movement system:

```rust
use specs::prelude::*;
use crate::components::{Position, Velocity, Antenna};
pub struct Movement;
impl<'a> System<'a> for Movement {
    type SystemData = (
        WriteStorage<'a, Position>,
        WriteStorage<'a, Velocity>,
    );

    fn run(&mut self, (mut position, velocity): Self::SystemData) {
        for(pos, vel) in (&mut position, &velocity).join() {
            pos.x += vel.x;
            pos.y += vel.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `run` simpler by forwarding to a function in `Movement`, and then test that function instead. Make this new function generic on P and V for position and velocity.

You'll probably need to add some traits for P and V and implement them for `WriteStorage` and whatever type you're going to use for testing, (maybe just &[f32])

Something like:

```
use specs::prelude::*;
use crate::components::{Position, Velocity, Antenna};
pub struct Movement;

trait ValueList<T> { /* ... */ }
impl<T> ValueList<T> for WriteStorage<'a, T> { /* ... */ }
impl<T> ValueList<T> for &[T] { /* ... */ }

impl Movement {
    fn run_impl<P,V>(position:P, velocity:V)
    where
        P: ValueList<Position>
        V: ValueList<Velocity>
    {
        for(pos, vel) in (&mut position, &velocity).join() {
            pos.x += vel.x;
            pos.y += vel.y;
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> System<'a> for Movement {
    type SystemData = (
        WriteStorage<'a, Position>,
        WriteStorage<'a, Velocity>,
    );

    fn run(&mut self, (mut position, velocity): Self::SystemData) {
        Self::run_impl(position, velocity);
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_run() {
   let p:Vec<Position> = vec![...];
   let v:Vec<Velocity> = vec![...];

   Movement::run_impl(p,v);
   ...
}
```